# How to make a graph in excel with 2 side by side x axis and one y axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

My question is how to figure a graph with 2 x-axis side by side with one y-axis. For clarification, i mean 2 x axis with minimum value (zero) at the middle and for example maximum value 15 at right for the first x axis and 20 at the left for the second x axis. While for y-axis, it will be in the middle intersecting with zero value.
Here is the link for the graph i need with the difference, i need both x values positive.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I believe the answer to you question is "yes". If you can [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1529140/edit) to provide some sample data, what you've tried so far and maybe an image of the expected result, then a more constructive answer may be possible. (you can upload images to http://imgur.com and link to them here)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I can see how to do this by making it -20 and then multiplying all the X values of the corresponding series by -1, but to keep them both positive in the same graph I am interested to see as I thought excel was limited to one X axis, unlike its potential dual Y axis option.  Looking forward to seeing how this is done.

Comment: Hi @Ahmed,, excel facilitate two Axis,, primary and secondary at but the place (in the middle) like screen shot show not looking possible,, may be some intermediate method could do this,, or if U check the Tableau ,, possibly has something like this !

Comment: ,, **continue,,** I'm sure that [this help U](https://help.plot.ly/excel/graph-with-multiple-axes/)

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming*** you can generate the graph and the only problem is the numbers on the horizontal axis you can do the following:

1. generate your graph as shown in your screencap.
2. select, then right-click on the bottom axis labels and choose "Format Axis from the dropdown menu

[image]

3. Under "Number" choose "Custom" and add the following custom number format:

   ```
   0; 0; 0
   ```

You chart's horizontal axis should now look like this:

[image]

With the data from the screencap in your comment below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, however i did what u said but it is still all values in the same arrangement without changing as cleared in the photo https://i.imgur.com/dDPpvFV.png. So from u opinion what's the problem.

Comment: You don't have any negative values for the X axis. See edit to my answer